# Dynamically parameters creation in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I've a requirement where I need to create parameters based on previous selection.

For example, if the user selected A and it has X values, it has to populate X number of dropdown parameters.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to create the maximum possible number of parameters and set them either to null, or the specific value based on this master parameter you are originally setting.

Comment: My requirement is like, Each selected parameter is able to take some value(Multiselect Dropdown Checkbox with Textbox for each). 
For example, If i selected A as parameter it has X values and each value should hold some number. I'm using that number in final dataset preperation. Is there any other way to achieve?

Comment: From what I understand if your question add it stands, no.

Comment: i want parameter like multi select check box with textbox each.

Answer (score 0):

If l have understood the question correctly?  What are looking for is a technique called cascading parameters.

These links give some details - :

[First example](https://www.resultdata.com/adding-cascading-parameters-to-a-ssrs-report/#lightbox/8/)

[Second example](http://sql-bi-dev.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/cascading-parameters-in-ssrs-2008.html)

The other requirement 'Multiselect Dropdown Checkbox with Textbox for each' with SSRS there is only one option that will give you this.  When setting up the report parameter that requires multiselect with checkbox and text.  Then ensure 'Allow multiple values' check box is selected (see figure below)

[image: SSRS report parameter - Allow multiple values check box]

Answer (score 0):

Create two parameters create @parameterA and then for the parameter B write your select as

```
Select * from table_X
Where field_x = @parameterA
```

And that will only populate the second parameters with values that are equal to the first selection.

See [Cascading Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255197.aspx).